# Ruby gem wrong installation directory

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems

I had Ruby 1.9.2 install, but I uninstalled it long ago. Today I installed a brand new version of Ruby 1.9.3, downloaded gem and set it up with `ruby setup.rb`.

I then noticed that installing gems failed, so I checked `gem environment` and this is what I get:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.11
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2011-10-30 patchlevel 0) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - C:/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
     - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

It seems messing up the new installation (Ruby193) with the old one (Ruby192).

`ruby -v` yields, correctly, `ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30) [i386-mingw32]`.

How to solve the problem?

**EDIT**: I had GEM_HOME and RUBYLIB environment variables set up to the old directories. Updating them solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to download gem or run ruby setup.rb.

I recommend removing all references to old rubies from your path environment variable and then downloading 1.9.3 from [rubyinstaller.org](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) install it and then download, install and run the [devkit](http://github.com/downloads/oneclick/rubyinstaller/DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20110712-1620-sfx.exe)